# Eclipse Build Path for common projects on different WildFly runtimes

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath, wildfly, ear

I need your help to understand what's the best way to organize our Ecplise environment since it's getting complicated.

We have 7 large multi-projects units which are deployed as distinct **EAR**s on different servers. We use WildFly on all of them however some are older whereas others are newer (they span from **WildFly 10 Runtime** to **WildFly 12 Runtime**)

Every EAR contains war/jar from other projects, some projects are common and they end up as a jar in every EAR. For instance let's say **Project Common** is a plain Java project which is included as a jar in all the 7 EARs.

The build path of **Project Common** is my problem, for example if **Project Common** requires Servlet api as a build path dependency, we used to add the Wildfly server runtime libraries to solve the problem but 
the actual version of the Wildfly server runtime libraries is different depending on the EAR you're dealing with (as I said they span from WildFly 10 Runtime to WildFly 12 Runtime).
When it will be deployed & running, **Project Common** will run within a specific WildFly server Runtime but in its buildpath (as an Eclipse project) which server-runtime are we supposed to enter? All of them are good and yet WildFly 12 Runtime might come with a Servlet API version which is different from the one provided by WildFly 10 Runtime.

Ideally what you want is to build **Project_Common.jar** with **the very same server-runtime library it will have when running in a specific EAR** but as I said that depends on which EAR you're working on at the moment.
In other words, the build path dependencies of **Project_Common.jar** are dynamic depending on the EAR it will be packged to run into (because it will be running on a different WildFly version)

So far we used a single giant workspace and 7 different Eclipse working-sets
however what I'm thinking is to have 7 different workspaces with **Classpath variables** that are different from workspace to workspace.
For example if **Project Common** requires javax.persistence API in its build path, instead of including a specific WildFly server runtime version (which will ship a specific version of javax.persistence), we might have just a classpath variable JAVAX_PERSISTENCE in every workspace that will be defined to point to the specific javax.persistence jar (specific to the WildFly Runtime it will be running).

What do you think? The "disadvantage" of this approach is that the 7 workspaces will all have their own copy of **Project Common** which will have to be kept up-to-date.

Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: A colleague of mine suggested to create a WildFly Runtime in Eclipse always with the same name (no matter the version) so that we can always add to the build path the "WildFly Runtime" which is always the same name in the .classpath file of eclipse and yet it actually is a specific WildFly version in that workspace. I'm not so keen on that because if a project only requires javax.persistence (a single jar) in the build path it's no point always adding an entire server runtime library in the build path.

Comment: Hilariously I think you have just answered your [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54636420/2071828).